# CSS vertical Table Layout

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table made of divs like this:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tRow A">
        <div class="tCell">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tRow B">
        <div class="tCell">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tRow C">
        <div class="tCell">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

.table{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.tRow{
    display: table-row;
}

.tCell{
    display: table-cell;
}

.B {
    background: yellow;
}

.B .tCell{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.C{
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HtA43/

Now what i need (and i am not able to get this working) is, that the table is rendered 100% height. `rowA` getting as high as its contents `rowC` with a fixed height at the bottom. And `rowB` should fill the rest of the space.

This works so far, but when the content of `rowB` exceeds its size, the cell and thus the table grows. What i need is that `rowB` does not grow but the overflow is hidden.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question here is why are you using that table layout to do that ?

Comment: Because i thought it would be the only way to achieve this. (One Row autoSized, one Fixed and a Fill Row in the middle) If you have suggestions not featuring a table layout that would be great as well.

Comment: Some suporrt needs? Wich version of IE you need?

Comment: We fully rely on HTML5, CSS3 and ECMA Script 5. Lowest supported IE is IE 10.

Answer (score 2):

On your requisits you have `overflow:hidden` that makes the layout more easy to acomplish. You can have an structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="A">
        Test
 </div>
 <div class="B">
     Test....
 </div>
 <div class="C">
        Test
 </div>
</div>
```

And then just a few styles:

```
.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.B {
  min-height:100%;
}
.C{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Check this [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HtA43/3/)

Comment: Definitely seems more like the way to go than rigid tabular lay-outs

Comment: i think this is almost what i need but the problem with this approach (one of the reasons why i usually prefer the div-table style) is that the middle 100% div reaches behind the bottom fixed one. (You could indeed set a padding to `B` with the size of `C` but some jquery plugins that i need to apply to `B` can't cope with that).

Comment: Actually `B` gets 100% height ob its container which is `container` which makes `B` always exceeding the container and reaching outside the page which makes it impossible to make it scrollable.

Comment: That's why I say the overflow:hideen make it more easier to make b scroll can use othe properties

Comment: To keep B an A dynamic and B scrollabel you may need Jquery @Chris

Comment: I currently have a case where A does not exist. Does this make it easier?